# PHP file input, accessing the content of the file

Tags: php

I am making a file input that takes in a txt file.  How do I access the contents of the file that just got uploaded using PHP?

Comment: In the future you can search for functions from http://php.net/, which is a very good reference.

Answer (score 2):

```
$contents = file_get_contents('/path/to/file');
```

Comment: @Lajos Arpad: I wonder if an answer can be longer for such question ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately they can, that's why I upvoted your answer: It helped the person who asked the question and didn't contain not needed arguments. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to access the file directly:

```
$content = file_get_contents($_FILES["file_input_field_name"]["tmp_name"]);
```

If you want to store the file, you'll want to check out:

http://php.net/move_uploaded_file

Comment: Also, make sure to use is_uploaded_file (http://us3.php.net/is_uploaded_file) before reading "uploaded" files & check error conditions.